# SQL query for build inbox of messages

Tags: mysql, sql

**Help with an SQL Query:**

I want to get the last message of every conversation between client and helper. Based on same clientId lets say clientId = 1 but different helperId. What I am trying to achieve is build an inbox where last only last message of the conversation is available.

Here is the table structure.
**Note:** The clientId is known in the table everyother field is not known.

Please have a look at the table structure below: [image]

Comment: what is you table structure , data  and what is your sql query ?

Comment: Add a condition of max(date time) from a nested query of select client is, max(datetime)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it this way:

```
$table    =    // table name
$clientId =    // client's id
$query    = "select * from ".$table." where `clientId`= '".$clientId."' group by `helperId` order by `id` desc";
```

This would give you the last conversation for the same client but with different helper.

Comment: Big big admiration for answering a losely specified question.

Comment: @LajosArpad thanks a lot, actually i think i understood his problem